# SQL Replication with advanced filter on data

Tags: sql-server, database, filter, database-replication

I want to replicate my local, internal database (publisher) to a public database (subscriber) with some restrictions: Not all rows/columns/data from the internal database should be replicated/pushed to the public database. Most important, some personal user data must be filtered (they must be excluded in the public database).

**Technology**

- Microsoft SQL Server 2014

**Example Table PERSON**

Source table on the internal database (publisher):

```
ID | NAME         | IS_PUBLIC | SOCIALNR | MARITAL_STATUS | MARITAL_STATUS_PUBLIC 
---+--------------+-----------+----------+----------------+---------------------
0  | Hans Muster  | 1         | 1234556  | married        | 1
2  | John Doe     | 1         | 5432167  | single         | 0
9  | Ingrid Meyer | 0         | 6789989  | single         | 0
```

**1. Filter: SOCIALNUMBER**

The column *SOCIALNR* should not be replicated at all. This can be achieved by using a column filter on the table. WORKS!

[image: replication column filter]

Target table on the public database (subscriber):

```
ID | NAME         | IS_PUBLIC | MARITAL_STATUS | MARITAL_STATUS_PUBLIC 
---+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------
0  | Hans Muster  | 1         | married        | 1
2  | John Doe     | 1         | single         | 0
9  | Ingrid Meyer | 0         | single         | 0
```

**2. Filter: Person if IS_PUBLIC**

A person should only be replicated, if the field *IS_PUBLIC* is set to true. If not, the person should not be public, so all his data should not be replicated. This can be achieved by using a row filter on the table. WORKS!

[image: replication row filter]

Target table on the public database (Subscriber):

```
ID | NAME         | IS_PUBLIC | MARITAL_STATUS | MARITAL_STATUS_PUBLIC 
---+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------
0  | Hans Muster  | 1         | married        | 1
2  | John Doe     | 1         | single         | 0
```

**3. Filter: MARTIAL_STATUS if public**

And now the specialty and the reason for this question: A person marital status should only be replicated, if the flag *MARTIAL_STATUS_PUBLIC* is set to true. If the flag is false, the value in *MARTIAL_STATUS* should be null or empty or whatever. All other person data should be replicated regardless of the flag.

Target table on the public database (Subscriber):

```
ID | NAME         | IS_PUBLIC | MARITAL_STATUS | MARITAL_STATUS_PUBLIC 
---+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------
0  | Hans Muster  | 1         | married        | 1
2  | John Doe     | 1         | NULL           | 0
```

Is there a possibility to fulfill this requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a workaround for my problem by using a schemabound indexed view. This view will be replicated to the Subscribers as a table.

For the example above the following steps are required:

1. Create a view from the *PERSON* Table called *REPLICATION_PERSON*
2. Set the view-attribute "Bind to Schema" to true and use the ID from the table *PERSON* as a unique clustered index
3. Use a SELECT-IF-Statement to set a field to null

   SELECT ..., (CASE WHEN MARTIAL_STATUS_PUBLIC = 1 THEN MARTIAL_STATUS ELSE NULL END)
4. Add the view to the "objects to publish" list by entering a Name (equal to the table: *PERSON*) and set the flag "Create schemas at Subscriber" to true

[image]

[image]

On the subscriber, the view will be generated as a table. If you want to use additional column/row-filters, you have to put them into your view with a "WHERE"-Statement.

also see: https://sqlship.wordpress.com/2010/04/14/replicate-indexed-views-transactional-replication/